# How can I disable the softkey backlight?

Tags: buttons, backlight

I've been using [Voodoo Display Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.displayfilter) to dim my screen further than the normal minimum at night, and it works great.  I want to do the same thing with the backlight for my touch buttons since it's incredibly bright.

I wrote a small script to try to do this:

```
cd /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/
while [1]; do
    echo 2 > brightness
    usleep 50000
done
```

This almost does the trick, but it seems to prevent some touches of the buttons from registering (presumably due to all the events being processed) and the light flickers when I touch one of the softkeys.  Is there any solution that avoids these issues?

[Total Screen Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=alex.munteanu.totalscreencontrol) doesn't really work and I'd rather have a free solution anyways, since I'm pretty close already.  I believe CyanogenMod lets you control this as well but I want to stay on my current ROM (Bionix NextGen v1).

Comment: Unsure about the Vibrant, but a custom kernel like Siyah for my S2 allows one to set the brightness for the backlight of the capacitive touch keys. Perhaps there's a kernel that offers similar functionality for your device?

Comment: @Sparx Possibly ... I use the Voodoo ext4 lagfix so I'd need to find a kernel that supports both.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Screen filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&hl=en) app in google play.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on my Nexus 4.

Comment: I have tried the app by Haxor that you linked to. Soft-key backlighting confirmed __*not*__ working on my Nexus 7, HTC One V, Acer Iconia a500, Kyocera Event, Samsung S2, nor Nextbook 8HD8G.